# Where has the flag for "nothing to do with programming" moved to?

Tags: support, questions, close-reasons

I see many questions in SO that are related to what a few months ago was:

"**nothing to do with programming language**"

Where was this flag moved? I can't see it anymore.

The only option I have is to close the question and give some description, but since the frequency is quite high, it must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're thinking of the "blatantly off-topic" flag reason:

> **Blatantly off-topic** - this question has nothing to do with $Topic

Users with less than 3k rep can't close vote, but are given the ability to close *flag* instead. This has no effect on how many close votes the question has, but if it's not already there, a close flag will push a post into the Close Votes review queue.

Close flags are not available to users with more than 3k rep; they're converted automatically into close votes. Additionally, the "blatantly off-topic" flag option is converted into the custom close vote reason.